# Domain vs Co-domain vs Support of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

As a sequel of my previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4347698/how-dos-a-random-variable-x-is-connected-with-the-set-over-which-is-uniformly?noredirect=1#comment9072568_4347698).

1. We say that $X$ is a random variable defined over $Y$, does it mean that $Y$ is the domain of the random variable?
2. Also we say that $X$ takes values in some set $Z$, is $Z$ again the domain or the co-domain
3. Referring to the support of a random variable, that is the union of all the sets that have strictly positive (ie non zero) probability with respect to the distribution of the random variable, do we refer to the domain or the co-domain of $X$. Namely, if $R_X$ is the support of $X$ are the following equivalent: "$X$ takes values in $R_X$" $\Leftrightarrow$  "$R_X$ is the support of $X$"?

P.S. If anyone would like to provide an example to explain the question above, I would appreciate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A random variable is defined *a priori* over some probability space, say $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mu).$ So, that is what they mean that "$X$ is defined over some set."

Then, $X:\Omega \to \mathbf{R}$ is a (ordinary) function that is measurable (for every interval $I$, $\{X \in I\} := X^{-1}(I)$ is an event, viz. belongs to $\mathscr{F}$). However, $X$ maps the probability measure $\mu$ from the probabilty space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mu)$ into $\mathbf{R}$ (and the Borel sets of $\mathbf{R}$, call them $\mathscr{B}_\mathbf{R}$). In other words, $X$ induces the new measure $F_X:\mathscr{B}_\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ from the original measure $\mu$ by setting $F_X(I) = \mu(X \in I).$  This $F_X$ is known as "distribution function of $X$" by the mathematicians and as "c.d.f. of X" (for "cumulative distribution function") by first year students and the statistician, although, admittedly, the "c." is redundant and unnecessary. Note that we can, at this point, discard $X$ and define a new random variable, say $X_{\mathrm{new}},$ on the probability space $(\mathbf{R}, \mathscr{B}_\mathbf{R}, F_X)$ by $X_{\mathrm{new}}:t \mapsto t$ (i.e. $X_\mathrm{new}$ is just the identity function). Then $X_\mathrm{new}$ also has distribution function $F_X.$ Thus, we can discard the original space where $X$ was defined and assume it was $\mathbf{R}$ all along; since the new $X$ is the identity function, questions over its domain and range are equivalent (and become ambiguous). Note that probabilistically, nothing is lost since $X$ is really just a device to transport $\mu$ from the "abstract probability space" onto the "Borel sets of $\mathbf{R}$."

The *support of $X$* is short-hand for the *support of the measure $F_X$* and is then the *complement of largest open set $O$ such that $F_X(O) = 0$* (i.e. is the smallest closed set where all the "mass of $X$" is concentrated). (Note that I used "mass of $X$" for this is short-hand for a more correct yet pendantic and cumbersome expression: "the mass assigned by $\mu$ on preimages by $X$ of Borel sets in $\mathbf{R}$.") I am a formally trained probabilist and questions about the "range of a random variable" usually never occur as this concept is admittedly ambiguous for random variables.

Comment: So, by saying that $X$ is defined over $Y$ it means that $Y$ is a standard probability space, namely $Y=(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$?

Comment: Short anser, yes.

Often, the probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, \mu)$ can be replaces without losing anything, so it is usually not mentioned. _If_ the domain of $X$ is important, it will be mentioned. In that situation, it would be expressed (perhaps tacitly assumed) what is the structure of probability space on the domain.

Comment: well your answer is almost perfect, but for me, is not so easy to get it. I have seen probability theory, but I am not a trained probabilist as you are and I am a bit confused. So I would appreciate if the answers were  shorter...you know as as I  can later get to understand the full information that you provide...

Comment: So, in a shorter answer then. When they say that $X$ takes values on $Y$ they mean that $Y$ is the probability space as well?

Comment: Yes. But do you have a particular example, from a book perhaps, where that phrase appears ("$X$ takes values on $Y$").

Comment: ok i have an example, take a look at this link here 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348465/could-i-prove-this-result-in-probability-theory-when-the-random-variables-are-de/4348523#4348523

it says in the end of the text ``If $l$ is a random variable with support on $G$ (since it takes vales on it) and $y$ is uniformly distributed over $G$ and independent of $l$, then the random variable defined as $x=l\ominus_{G}y$ is also uniformly distributed over $G$."

Comment: They are using the term support in the same way I did. $l$ is defined on some probability space (not mentioned) with values on/over/in $G$ (the abelian group), and the support of $l$ is a subset of $G$ (the OP there write "on" and whether you should write "on", "in", "over", etc is a matter os speech: random variables are abstract objects in our minds, they aren't real like air or water, so they literally cannot be in, on, over, etc, so either way of expressing it is fine, it just amount to what mental image you are using).